# How do I get past "Gecko engine crashed.;Gecko engine crashed.;Gecko engine crashed.;" error after upgrading abcPDF

Tags: gecko, abcpdf

I recently upgraded abcPDF from v8.1.0.7 to v8.1.1.1 (and then later from v8.1.1.1 to v8.1.1.2). After the upgrades, I got errors similar to the following whenever I tried to generate a PDF:

- "Gecko engine failed to render the page: Gecko engine crashed.; Gecko
  engine crashed...;"
- "Failed to add HTML:Gecko engine crashed.; Gecko
  engine crashed.; Gecko engine crashed..."

We're using the Gecko engine (instead of the default MSHTML engine) to render PDFs. We didn't get the error message until immediately after we upgraded abcPDF. This is in a .Net Framework 4.0 / C# / ASP.Net web application, hosted on 64-bit Windows Server 2008 R2.

How do I get past this error?

Answer (score 5):

Here's how I solved the problem (in case anyone out there has the same issue): I had originally installed the newer version of abcPDF without uninstalling the old version, first. To get past the error, here's what I did:

- Uninstalled all versions of abcPDF from the server;
- Confirmed that the GAC (c:\windows\assembly) did not contain any copies of abcPDF assemblies
- Reinstalled the latest version of abcPDF (8.1.1.2, at time of writing)
- Confirmed that all web.config files referenced the 8.1.1.2 version of the abcPDF assembly.

Once I did all of the above, I was able to render PDFs without errors once again.

Comment: Sure enough, what I thought was an upgrade was actually a concurrent install, which broke the component! Your solution worked. I uninstalled all abcpdf stuff, re-installed the latest, and all was well!