# (ABCPdf) Failed to add HTML: RPC to Gecko engine process failed

Tags: .net, iis, gecko, abcpdf

I have an MVC .NET application that uses ABCPdf to generate and serve PDF files.
It runs fine on several of our development machines, but there is a machine that cannot run it.

The machine is a Windows Server 2003 - 32 bit.

We first attempted to bin deploy all of the ABCPdf files, but we got this error.  After installing ABCpdf on the machine, we are still getting this error.

This is the error we are getting (before and after installing ABCPdf):

```
WebSupergoo.ABCpdf8.Internal.PDFException: Failed to add HTML: RPC to Gecko engine process failed.Remote process terminated unexpectedly.
[PDFException: Failed to add HTML: RPC to Gecko engine process failed.Remote process terminated unexpectedly.]
   WebSupergoo.ABCpdf8.Doc.AddUrl(String url, Boolean paged, Int32 width, Boolean disableCache) +181
   WebSupergoo.ABCpdf8.Doc.AddImageUrl(String url, Boolean paged, Int32 width, Boolean disableCache) +78
   WebSupergoo.ABCpdf8.Doc.AddImageUrl(String url) +64
```

Is there a dependency that we may be missing?  Is there something we need to configure on the server machine?

Edit: The machine in question a more secure and restrictive environment.  If this error seems to indicate a permissions issue, please suggest some ideas related to ABCPdf permissions.

Edit2:

We tried to run the simple project found here: http://www.websupergoo.com/support.htm#deploy http://www.websupergoo.com/download/testscripts8net.zip

This project gave us the same error, which may indicate that this is NOT a permissions issue.

ABCPdf7 was also installed on this machine, so we tried the suggestion from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9706680/320623
But that also did not help.

Thanks

Comment: I get this error too, but mine is being caused by ABCPDF trying to convert a webpage to a 60 page PDF. I assume its some sort of internal timeout?

Comment: My antivirus is actively blocking a process that's spawned by ABCpdf... Very annoying

Comment: Antivirus was too zealous in my case, deleted abcpdf exe

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure that the installed ABCpdf version on developer machines? To me it seems that compatability between minor versions of ABCpdf is a little difficult to handle - especially if running multiple solutions that use different versions of ABCpdf on the same machine/server. So do pay attention to exact version numbers - 8.1.0.6 to 8.1.0.7 can seemingly screw you over.

Try to copy the files in `%ProgramFiles%\WebSuperGoo\ABCpdf .NET 8.1\ABCGecko` from a working machine to the one that doesn't. (You might have to stop the process `abcgeckowp` first, it will restart automatically on first PDF-generating request).

Worked for me when I got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

It has been some time, but I believe that the problem was that I was actually missing some files in my bin deploy.  Feel free to downvote.

Comment: I'm seeing this same problem right now, so I wouldn't be downvoting anyone ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link - http://devio.wordpress.com/category/abcpdf/ Seems to be promising.

In my case I was able to get a working solution by moving the server, so never got to the root cause of this issue.